# Knapsack: Adding items from lists (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to write a code for a Knapsack problem. Where there is a knapsack with a weight capacity and you pick a certain combination of items to find the best possible solution. I'm trying to randomly generate the possible solutions. So my code will pick a random number of random items (generate a random sized list) and test to see if the solution is feasible (less than the capacity) or infeasible (more than the capacity). However, when I try to add up the total weight and the total value of all the items, the number is off. Say for instance, this is the data of each item.

```
Itms    Wts     Vals   
=====================
1       22      80
2       29      35
3       12      36
4       14      24
5       29      41
6       30      87
7       18      10
8       22      63
9       12      66
```

10       27      72

Here would be the result after running the code:

```
Items picked:  [6, 4, 1, 7, 8, 3]
Feasible:  Total Wt =  18 Total Val =  10
Items picked:  [1]
Infeasible:  Total Wt =  135 Total Val =  264
Items picked:  [5, 1, 8, 6, 7, 4]
Infeasible:  Total Wt =  89 Total Val =  198
```

So the values are incorrect. But I don't see what is wrong in my code:

```
def genSoln(cap,items):
    g = input("Would you like to generate random potential solutions? [y/n] ")
    if g == 'y':
        gen = int(input("Number of times to generate/check random potential solutions? "))
        totalwt = 0
        totalval = 0
        for i in range(1,gen+1):
            pop = range(1,items)
            leng = random.randint(1,len(pop))
            ran = random.sample(pop, leng)
            for i in ran:
                totalwt += int(wts[i])
                totalval += int(vals[i])
                if i == len(ran):
                    if totalwt < int(cap):
                        print("Items picked: ", ran)
                        print("Feasible: ", "Total Wt = ", totalwt, "Total Val = ", totalval)
                    else:
                        print("Items picked: ", ran)
                        print("Infeasible: ", "Total Wt = ", totalwt, "Total Val = ", totalval)
                    totalwt = 0
                    totalval = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured out the answer myself. I just needed to take out `if i == len(ran):` , move `totalwt` and `totalval` into the for loop (`for i in range(1,gen+1)`), and subtract 1 from i when adding to `totalwt`and  `totalval`.

```
def genSoln(cap,items):
    g = input("Would you like to generate random potential solutions? [y/n] ")
    if g == 'y':
        gen = int(input("Number of times to generate/check random potential solutions? "))
        for i in range(1,gen+1):
            totalwt = 0
            totalval = 0
            pop = range(1,items)
            leng = random.randint(1,len(pop))
            ran = random.sample(pop, leng)
            for i in ran:
                totalwt += int(wts[i-1])
                totalval += int(vals[i-1])
            if totalwt < int(cap):
                print("Items picked: ", ran)
                print("Feasible: ", "Total Wt = ", totalwt, "Total Val = ", totalval)
            else:
                print("Items picked: ", ran)
                print("Infeasible: ", "Total Wt = ", totalwt, "Total Val = ", totalval)
```